# Home link in the homepage of my wordpress does not show my blog posts

Tags: frontpage

I want the home link at the top of my theme in word press to display all the posts i have written so far but when clicking on it the page shows nothing.

I have already tried changing the settings as in:
Going to ***Settings***, then inside ***Readings***, I had **Front page displays** as **A static page** and within it I chose **Home** as **Front page** but even then i get no desired result.

I can only display all my posts on my website, when i click on my homepage address lets say www.queries999.com but when i go to www.queries999.com/home, it shows a blank page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays* select **Your latest posts**.  Go to *Appearance -> Menus*. You'll see as the first item **Home**, which points to the physical page 'Home'. Remove **Home** item from the menu. Expand *Custom Links*. Enter **/** ( right slash ) into *URL* field. Enter **Home** into *Link Text* field. Click on *Add to Menu* button. Drag your **Home** to the top of the menu. Save it. Now delete your physical page 'Home'.

**Update**: If you don't have a menu defined, yet, you'll have to create one. Go to *Appearance -> Menus*. Click on `create a new menu`link. Enter your desired menu name in *Menu Name* field and click on *Create Menu* button. First add your **Home** custom link as explained before. Continue adding other menu items. When done, select **Primary** checkbox in *Display location* group. Click on *Save Menu* button. All done.

Comment: Before reading your answer I had already deleted the Home page. So I started following you from second step. But upon going to Custom Links inside Menus in Appearance, I find that the Custom Links portion including the Pages and Post are all greyed out. But still I went on and tried entering one right slash into URL field and Home into Link Text Field and then tried on clicking the Add to Menu button. But the button is inactive or greyed and no desired changes take place. I have taken a screenshot of my page and uploaded the same here: pasteboard.co/3fP8xmzJo.jpg Thanks again

Comment: Your screenshot explains it. You don't have a menu created, yet. Please tell me. what theme do you use, and I'll update my answer, adding explanation, how to create a menu.

Comment: The name of the theme is ajaira.

Comment: Any chance you went through that theme? I tried creating a page by name of "Home"but it still does not solve my original purpose. So if you get any time then please try to help me here

Comment: Delete page 'Home' and then follow steps in my answers.